# How to create a bottom navigation bar on the left of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a **Flutter** web app, and I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar on the left of the screen like this screenshot shows:

[image]

I can't find a good solution to implement it. I tried creating a navigation bar from scratch but I had problems when navigating to screens that aren't the 4 ones that are showing on the side navigation bar (Home, Products, Suppliers and Workers). I wanted to try to use a `Drawer` but I don't know how to keep that drawer open all the time, because the side navigation bar showing in the screen above must be visible all the time, and I think it's not the appropriate way to implement it.

Comment: I have a similar application for tablets, where i use the `Row` and and `expanded` children with flex of 1:4 or more/less, on the right i have the `pageView` that way you can get the swiping animations on change of pages. You Can put the `pageView` as NeverScrollable so it wouldn't change on swiping, will just change from the left panel.

Answer (score 0):

wrap sidebar and main page with expanded individually inside the row, flex should be provided to both expanded with widgets in the ratio 1:2 or what you like